# Installation Failure on MacBook Pro (2Ghz/Core i7)

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro

I've downloaded the ISO of 14.04.1 and written it to a DVD successfully, using Disk Utility. The disc verifies successfully. I've also made a bootable .img USB drive using the instructions provided on the Ubuntu site. I don't get any errors in Terminal. In both cases, as soon as the USB/DVD creation has completed, I get a message saying 'This disk You Inserted was not readable by this computer'. The USB stick is confirmed as unreadable by a second Mac (broken drive, so I can't test the DVD), however, since both were written on the same machine that now refuses to recognise them, I'm confident this isn't an issue with the media itself. Is there are known Mac related bug here or has anyone else encountered the same fault and found a workaround?

Comment: I downloaded the 64 bit version of 14.04.1. AFAIK there is only one ISO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 64 bit [Mac iso.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac.iso)  [Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37999/what-is-different-about-the-mac-iso-image) an explanation of what is different about it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the +mac iso linked above, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hi John.  Sorry I didn't see that you were trying to use a USB install.  That's a problem in itself (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key).  Are you getting the same error with DVD or USB or both?

Comment: Hi - I'm getting the same error with DVD as with USB. It's DVD that I want to get to work.