# When trying to install on Mac: "No mountable file system."

Tags: system-installation, mac

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2 - desktop. When I try to open the file, I have the following error message:

```
NO MOUNTABLE FILE SYSTEM.
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

Comment: I remember it was a bear getting it installed on my Mac. What model Mac do you have? And what steps have you taken to try and install it? (I'd post this as a comment but don't have high enough reputation yet.)

Comment: Which file are you trying to open?

Answer (score 3):

First in order to create a bootable USB on mac for Ubuntu you should follow these instructions I took from the Arch Wiki:

To be able to use dd on your USB device on a Mac you have to do some special maneuvers. First of all insert your usb device, OS X will automount it, and in Terminal.app run:
    diskutil list

Figure out what your USB device is called with mount or `sudo dmesg | tail` (e.g. `/dev/disk1`) and unmount the partitions on the device (i.e., `/dev/disk1s1`) while keeping the device proper (i.e., `/dev/disk1`):

```
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1
```

Now we can continue in accordance with the instructions above (but, if you are using the OS X `dd`, use `/dev/rdisk` instead of `/dev/disk`, and use `bs=1m`. `rdisk` means "raw disk" and is much faster on OS X, and `bs=1m` indicates a 1 MB block size).

```
# dd if=image.iso of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m

20480+0 records in
20480+0 records out
167772160 bytes transferred in 220.016918 secs (762542 bytes/sec)
```

It is probably a good idea to eject your drive before physical removal at this point:

```
diskutil eject /dev/disk1
```

After that install Refind as that should make booting into the USB installation of Ubuntu easy and then reboot your computer and select the USB.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to open the file

This is not an application or software installer and this is not how you install Ubuntu. You need to create a bootable medium, [boot it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417), and [then you can install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/6328/40581). Macs with up to date firmware should behave like standard UEFI computers with Windows 8 or later, which means just follow the standard instructions. If they work, good for you, if not, follow [karel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/655232/40581).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ubuntu ISOs have some partition map shenanigans that make them unreadable using regular OS X tools. At least that's true for Ubuntu 15.10 and Mac OS X 10.8, but there are reports on the web regarding other versions too.

The only tool I was able to find that can successfully burn a Ubuntu ISO to USB is [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/). Make sure to prepare the USB drive first with Disk Utility, choosing 1 Partition, GUID partition table (in the Options button) and MS-DOS FAT partition type.

I have not tried the resulting USB on my Mac, but it installed cleanly on a Windows PC, while no other method worked, including `dd` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

ISO or DMG should be created *from a valid file system*. For instance:

```
$ diskutil list

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 GB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage FER_PEN                 3.7 GB     disk3s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk3s3
/dev/disk4 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS FER_PEN                +3.5 GB     disk4
                                 Logical Volume on disk3s2
                                 96D32D40-6F89-41A0-AA56-89D904A15295
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

The only valid filesystem is Apple_HFS, thus I issue:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk4 of=pen.dmg bs=1m
```