# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on an iMac with a blank hard drive

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, mac

I have an iMac 2009 model, and a new hard drive. I wanted to know what's the easiest way to get ubuntu installed on it.

I've looked everywhere and found only old answers, or things that don't apply. I'm guessing my e2b USB drive won't be useful here. I have other usb drives, but no idea how to get started.

Thanks for your help, and have a great day.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! You cannot harm a computer with a blank hard drive, so please give it a try and then report if it did not work. I have successfully booted 2007 Macs using USB drives created using [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i wasn't afraid to harm it, just wondering how to prepare the drive, and boot to it. Was looking for someone with experience with this.

Comment: From the target found by @karel, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/283924/250300) is what I’ve done but with OS X installed. Try creating the bootable USB drive on another computer and report if it boots. I think current Ubuntu ISO’s can be booted without rEFInd but I had to use it for the [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) boot manager.

Answer (score 1):

In general there are 3 steps involved.

1. Create a live USB from the [Ubuntu Desktop installation ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) file.
2. Booting up the live USB by inserting the USB on the Mac, hold down Command-C while powering up with the power button and select to boot with the live USB.
3. Install Ubuntu allowing it to use the entire disk and handle the partitioning also.

After installation has completed, it will ask you to remove the live USB and proceed to reboot. If you run into problem in any of the steps above, please post issues here to get further help.

Good luck.