# Installing Ubuntu on an IMAC mid 2010 High Sierra

Tags: mac

How can I install Ubuntu on my IMAC mid 2010 High Sierra?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.10 on an iMac 2009. I removed HighSierra totally.It was pretty straight forward.

- I downloaded the ISO
- I created a USB key with [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) under HighSierra
- I rebooted with Alt key pressed and chose the USB key as the boot volume (i.e.: "EFI Boot" instead of "Macintosh HD")
- I followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Single-Boot:_Ubuntu_Only) for single boot and voilà!

I could even run Try Ubuntu before installing it.
Everything worked right out of the box. (except [my mouse cursor issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323183/ubuntu-20-10-on-mac-mouse-cursor-disappears-randomly))