# Ubuntu 20.10 on mac: Mouse cursor disappears randomly

Tags: mouse, amd-graphics, mac, 20.10, cursor

The mouse cursor disappears after a while. It happens randomly with any software (Chrome, Skype, terminal, LibreOffice etc...). The mouse still works though.It just the cursor which disappears.
I cannot find a pattern why it disappears or what makes it disappear. The only fix is to reboot (logout does not work).
It works for a while after the reboot, then it disappears again.
It only disappears when I move the mouse which makes me thing it could a be GPU driver bug (the screen is not redrawn correctly). I could be wrong obviously.

I've tried standard login and Wayland. It happens with both. I guess it's related to the hardware as I tried the same Ubuntu version on a different computer with an Intel GPU and it does not occur on it.

Only Ubuntu is installed on the drive (macOS is not). Ubuntu detects the GPU as Rv730.

Is there a way I can bring the cursor back without rebooting?

Comment: Is this a usb mouse? What happens when you disconnect & connect the usb port? What messages are logged in `syslog`?

Comment: It's a wireless with USB dongle, but I also with 2 other USB wired mouses and it still happens.

k: [ 2378.095473] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 8
k: [ 2382.536188] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
k: [ 2382.781441] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=24.11
k: [ 2382.781444] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
...
k: [ 2382.809327] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.000C: hiddev0,hidraw0:

(FYI, "k:" is for "kernel:")

Comment: If you unplug the usb mouse, wait a few seconds, and then plug it back in , does the cursor come back?

Comment: It does not, the only solution is to reboot. 
I found a temporary workaround: Set `SWCursor` to `on` in Xorg.conf, but the cursor often blinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to a software mouse cursor fixed it for me.
https://www.reddit.com/r/freebsd/comments/chjalp/xorg_cursor_disappeared/

Basically adding an xorg section for SWCursor:

> create just a tiny file named something like '`swcursor.conf`' under
> `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` containing the following:
>
> ```
>     Section "Device"
>        Identifier "device1"
>        Option "SWcursor"
>     EndSection
> ```

Comment: Yep, that's why I said in my previous comment :-). Thank you for sharing the whole xorg configuration. But in my case, it flickers too much. It's really annoying.

Comment: @zetoune did you ever get a better solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: Adding this file did nothing for me.  The cursor just seems to randomly disappear. I have noticed that if I make a Remmeina connection from my laptop, the system works in the Remmina window.

Comment: This solution is not usable long term it looks awful

Comment: @AndrewT, nope. I did not.