# 'No mountable disk' on macOS Catalina (Intel Processor)

Tags: mount

I am trying to download the latest Ubuntu. I am able to download it, but when I try to open it, it gives me this error:

"The following disk images couldn't be opened" **"Reason- no mountable file systems"**

I have tried following directions online, but I can't seem to get anywhere.
Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Why you are trying to "open" an iso file.

Comment: Please be specific with details; latest Ubuntu means what?  In July 2022 the Ubuntu Core 22 product was released, so do you mean that?  Before that it was Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in April 2022, but that came out in many forms (desktop, server & *flavor* products).... and I've not mentioned *daily* images used in QA  ie. being specific allows us to better understand you.  Do you mean Ubuntu Core 22 being last months release?

Comment: Instructions for making a bootable media are available at the exact sa,e site where you download the ISO from: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my Mac to boot from an Ubuntu USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key)