# "The created USB device will not boot off a Mac."

Tags: macbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot from USB on a Macbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17333/boot-from-usb-on-a-macbook)

I tried to make my USB drive for Ubuntu using unetbootin but after it finished loading the os on usb drive, i get this message: "The created USB device will not boot off a Mac. Insert it into a PC, and select the USB boot option in the BIOS boot menu." Anybody has any idea?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question. It's specific to the message "The created USB device will not boot off a Mac" on the unetbootin tool. The answer is, ignore this message, and boot with the option key pressed - it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS requires that you have an OSX install on the USB media in order to boot from it.  I don't particularly care for this practice, but it is true.  See the previous post on the matter [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17333/boot-from-usb-on-a-macbook).